# What can i use instead of 'for' loop in solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
function pickWinner() restricted candidatesLimit view returns(string){
    uint winner;
    uint max= 0;
    for(uint i=0; i < candidatesCount; i++){
        Candidates storage candidate = candidates[i];
        if(candidate.votingCounts > max){
            winner = i;
        }
    }
    Candidates storage winnerCandidate = candidates[winner];
    return (winnerCandidate.name);
}
```

I used for loop in here but i'm worried about big gas fees what can i use instead of "for" in here?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements it is sometimes possible to remove a loop (and its array) and use mappings instead. But that's only true if your data structure can be represented with a mapping and if you don't really need to iterate over it (you can't iterate over a mapping).

Comment: Could u please give me a example code about it?